# Find Unique Records in nested foreach loop on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, loops, foreach, nested, unique

I am trying to fetch multiple posts from different tags followed by a single user.

A post has multiple tags for example:-
"great berries with no chalks" (`consumer web` , `big data`) 
"effective ways to declare drought" (`consumer web` , `sql`)

A user follows multiple tags for example:-
John *follows* `consumer web` , `big data`

So when John logs in he sees posts from the tags `consumer web` and `big data`.
From the example above , the John's home page shows him the below results. The problem is they are repeated result of the same post.

"great berries with no chalks"
"great berries with no chalks"

Rails Code:

```
<% @tags.each do |mytag| %>
        <% @posts = Post.tagged_with(mytag.name) %>  

        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
               <div> <%= post.title %></div>
        <% end %> 

<% end %>
```

So when John logs in , controller determines his followed tags and passes these tags to the object (@tags). Then the above loop runs twice for each tag and returns the same post since it belongs to both tags.

I want to improve the code so that it can return only 1 result even if it finds the posts belongs to multiple tags followed by the same user. Essentially an unique result for multiple tags. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Post.tagged_with(mytag.name).uniq`?